# Verilog Multiplier/Divider Propagation Delay

Tags: verilog, propagation, timedelay

I'm about to start coding a basic shift multiplier and a shift divider structurally in Verilog, but I wanted to first figure out what the expected propagation delays should be. Does anyone know the propagation delay equations for basic shift multipliers and dividers?

Answer (score 0):

May be being more specific can help us answer your question more accurately. The expected delays and actual hardware depends on the method you use to implement your circuit.

May be [this PDF](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~asim/COEN_6501/project_Giovanni_D'Aliesio.pdf) can provide some help regarding simulation and timing.

Answer (score 0):

Not Only does this depend on the multiplier and divider architecture used but the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_scale_examples) and voltage you run the circuit at.

For example at 350nm, 1.3v you will struggle to meet timing at 100MHz. While at 14nm, 1.0v @ 1GHz you will not have a problem.

If you have the manual for your standard cell library it should list propagation delays for a given voltage for each cell.